# Error when copying an empty choice field from Excel into a SharePoint 2013 Datasheet View

Tags: 2013, excel, datasheet

Once in a while, we need to upload a whole list of Project Ideas into our SharePoint 2013 Enterprise system.

There is a datasheet view to copy all the fields from Excel into the list. Some of the choice fields are left blank in the Excel, and this causes the error " " is not a valid value" when I paste the items into the list. How do I get around this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone have an answer for this yet?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem at the moment. Didn't find a solution yet. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

In this kind of situations, I modify the column and make it allow fill in choices. Then I upload the data, which will not fail, and then change the allow fill in choices option back to No.

Answer (score 1):

Best advice I can offer you is to create a value in the choice column of your list.

 Call it something like: N/A

 

 
SharePoint choice fields data actually looks like [ID];#[Text Value]

 
In order for your no to manipulate your data in your excel sheet for SharePoint to except the data, you will need to determine what the ID of that choice value is.

 
So, in the ribbon of your SP List, choose, export to excel, check what the actual value of the newly created item is, copy that value.

 

 
In your excel sheet, create a formula to find and change all empty values in that column to the value you just got from the export.

Good luck